# power of a test, alternate definition

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

The usual definition of power of a test is $1-\beta$ (type II error). Given that a type II error is not rejecting $H_0$ when $H_{alternative}$ is true, is this equivalent to saying **power is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_{alternative}$ is true**?

That formulation seems much easier to parse, so I suspect I missed some nuance. On the other hand, rejecting and not rejecting are mutually exclusive, right? So I don't know what I might have missed...

Comment: You might find it fruitful to [search the Web for your rephrasing.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=power+is+the+probability+of+rejecting)

Comment: That seems to be the standard interpretation of power:  Correctly rejecting the null when it is false.

Comment: No. It is a common mistake, one of many side effects caused by Fisher's abuse of Pearson's work. The power is not just "the probability of correctly rejecting the null", but rather "the probability of correctly rejecting the null in favor of an alternative simple hypothesis". Just like p-value not being "the probability that the null is false" but rather "the probability of rejecting the null in favor of a powerful simple alternative".

Oh, and then there's the semantic problem with "rejecting the null" as it cannot be rejected, but that's for another day.

Answer (score 3):

Your phrasing is probably good enough for most purposes, but it could be improved by inclusion of mention of the statistical model and the fact that the particular alternative hypothesis is just one value of effect size among, usually, an infinite set of alternatives.

An alternative hypothesis has to be specified to perform a power calculation, but you will gain a much better appreciation of power from a graph of power as a function of the effect size. See the graphs in section 2.5 of this: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286